# ros_control without gazebo?

Tags: ros, gazebo, ros-control

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've used ros control multiple times for commanding joint positions in gazebo mainly following the rrbot example, but never in a real robot or a stripped down non-gazebo simulation.  How is it done, and is there an example?

As I understand it libgazebo_ros_control is loaded as a plugin into gazebo, then the controller_manager spawner asks it to create a controller for each joint specified.  Is there a generic non-gazebo service provider of `controller_manager/load_controller` that subscribes to joint feedback (derived from encoders) and desired joint position/velocity/effort and publishes joint commands according to the controller type and gain parameters?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/237944/ros_control-without-gazebo?/) by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) on ROS Answers with karma: 8729 on 2016-06-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is only a partial answer, but have a look at Dave Coleman's [ros_control_boilerplate](https://github.com/davetcoleman/ros_control_boilerplate).

The `gazebo_ros_control` package is essentially just one implementation of a `ros_control` `hardware_interface` subclass/plugin, which together with a node running the `read()`/`write()` loop (which may be run from a hard real-time task, or from a regular `pthread`, or something else) forms the bulk of a `ros_control` setup.

For a real piece of hardware, the process to setup `ros_control` is exactly the same, apart from the fact that you'll have to provide a `hardware_interface` implementation for your platform. After that, (almost) everything else is the same.

I highly recommend to view the [presentation](https://vimeo.com/107507546) Adolfo gave at ROSCon14 if you haven't already.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2016-06-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2